# How to load modal content via ajax bootstrap pagination without reloading main page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I have used bootstrap modal and will paginate for modal content pagination. But everytime i click the next/prev button, the entire page (includes main window) gets loaded

**scripting lines:**

```
$("#ajax_process_page").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('/modal_file')) %>");

$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on("click", ".pagination a", function() {
  $(".pagination").html("<img src='/images/feed-loader.gif' align='middle' />");
  $.getScript(this.href);
  });
});
```

**html code:**

```
<div id="ajax_process_page">
      <% render "/modal_file" %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add more context?
Your .pagination is inside your #ajax_process_page?

Comment: ya its inside the modal.. mean at footer of modal window as
<%= will_paginate @newsemailgifs, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails, bootstrap: 3, :page_links => false %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll need more information to help you, however, we can try somethings. It looks like you are clicking on a link. Maybe that's why it keeps reloading. If that's the case, you can fix it using [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), like code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("click", ".pagination a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".pagination").html("<img src='/images/feed-loader.gif' align='middle' />");
    $.getScript(this.href);
  });
});
```

Comment: I have tried this one already but the thing is, if i provide preventdefault(); concept then only the /images/feed-loader.gif image gets loading and nothing more..

Comment: But that's still the point, if you're problem is a full reload of the page, the preventDefault is what you need. Try to explain more, show us the content  inside the modal (<% render "/modal_file" %>).

Comment: I am quite confused @sathishkumar. You said your problem was page reloading. Can you please provide what is the behaviour you are expecting?